# SHAREPOINT AUTHENTICATION URL

Tags: sharepoint-server

I´m trying to connect my application with Sharepoint through the REST API. I´ve an authentication problem, because I don´t know the URL adress of the login page because when I connect to the sharepoint server, I automatically jump a window to authenticate, but it does not take me to an authentication page. It is what is called "digest authentication". Dou know if there is an authentication URL? Thank you

Comment: Did you help my answer? Mark it please.

Answer (score 2):

Try example in this [post 1](http://www.whypad.com/posts/authenticate-sharepoint-rest-call-in-a-rest-client/1169/) or this [post 2](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/a3b81bbe-487e-4498-adbe-5e48f33585af/sharepoint-2013-remote-authentication-in-rest-api?forum=sharepointdevelopment). I hope it will works for you well.

**Post 2**

In on-premise, we can use NetworkCredential to pass the Credentials for the REST request.

```
var siteUrl = "http://sp2013/sites/team";
var listName = "CustomList";
var loginName = @"domain\username";
var password = "xxx";

HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(siteUrl+"/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('"+listName+"')/items");

endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
NetworkCredential cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(loginName,password);
endpointRequest.Credentials = cred;
HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
try
{
    WebResponse webResponse = endpointRequest.GetResponse();
    Stream webStream = webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webStream);
    string response = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    JObject jobj = JObject.Parse(response);
    JArray jarr = (JArray)jobj["d"]["results"];
    foreach (JObject j in jarr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(j["Title"]);
    }
    responseReader.Close();
    Console.ReadLine();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    Console.Out.WriteLine(e.Message); Console.ReadLine();
}
```